# Parse email address

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, email-address

I am writing VBA code in Outlook 2007 to extract email address from emails.

I am able to read the body as a whole through a variable

How do I extract email address from the variable?

Answer (score 0):

One method is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977200/outlook-macro-extract-email-from-string-with-variable-length).

```
sString = "my1@email.com xxx my2@email.com yyy my3@email.com"
asString = Split(sString, " ")
For i = 0 To UBound(asString)
    If asString(i) Like "*@*.*" Then
        sEmail = sEmail & "," & asString(i)
    End If
Next

MsgBox Mid(sEmail, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the body? Have you looked at the MailItem.Recipients collection (Recipient.Address) and the MailItem.SenderEmailAddress property?

Comment: I believe the addresses are part of body of the mail. Not recipients.

Comment: Is that what the *original poster* has in mind? I am trying to see why the body rather than recipients need to be processed. And if the data is in the message body, who put it there? Is it in a special format?

Comment: The body of the email is in the "variable". The OP wants to parse the variable. Future searchers may find this is the answer to their question.

Comment: You are missing my point: is the OP parsing the message body because he/she is unaware of the other message properties? Or because the message was sent by some automatized process that populates the body with email addresses?