# Extract email address from string with variable length

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I extract an email address from a string?

> xxx my@email.com yyy

xxx and yyy can be any length, any character. The email address is delimited by spaces.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

```
sString = "my1@email.com xxx my2@email.com yyy my3@email.com"
asString = Split(sString, " ")
For i = 0 To UBound(asString)
    If asString(i) Like "*@*.*" Then
        sEmail = sEmail & "," & asString(i)
    End If
Next

MsgBox Mid(sEmail, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! it really works. This issuse was killing me digging in the regular expresions...